# Is it possible to use Diab with CMake?

Tags: cmake

I'd like to know if I can use Cmake with Diab. Diab doesn't seem to be in the list, but as I've read, it is possible.
No information is available on the docs.

Comment: Yes, although it's an old example, it seems someone created their own toolchain and platform files for Diab, documented in this [thread](https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2010-September/039579.html).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect question post to contain a **specific problem** (question), which can be answered. However, it is not clear what do you ask. The question in the title - "Is it possible to use Diab with CMake?" - is already answered in the question post - "I've read, it is possible.". So, what do you want from us?